# Vuejs 2.0 Multiple Category Filters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to do multi-category filtering with vuejs 2. I struggled a bit for this but the filtering process is not working.

I know how to do filtering operations with the computed method.

When I try this, I can only list the data for a single category.If I choose another category, the data comes out empty.I do not understand where I am making mistakes?

My Example : https://jsfiddle.net/a3x374qy/9/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedEatCategories:[],
    eatCategories : [
      {
       id:1,
        title: 'Category 1',
      },{
       id:2,
        title: 'Category 2',
      },{
       id:3,
        title: 'Category 3',
      },{
       id:4,
        title: 'Category 4',
      },{
       id:5,
        title: 'Category 5',
      }
    ],
    posts: [
      {
        id:1,
        title:'Product 1',
        eat_categories: [
         {
           id:1,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:2,
        title:'Product 2',
        eat_categories: [
         {
           id:1,
          },
          {
           id:2,
          },
          {
           id:3,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:3,
        title:'Product 3',
        eat_categories: [
         {
           id:1,
          },
          {
           id:5,
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
   filteredPlaces: function () {
       return this.posts.filter((j) => {
                   return (j.eat_categories.includes(this.checkedEatCategories));
                });
            }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
<ul>
   <li v-for="eatCategory in eatCategories">
     <label>
        <input type="checkbox" :value="eatCategory.id" v-model="checkedEatCategories">
        <span class="title">{{eatCategory.title}}</span>
     </label>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li v-for="post in posts">
    {{ post.title }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues here.

1. You're looping through `posts` instead of `filteredPlaces` in your template
2. `.includes()` doesn't accept an array. Try combining it with `.some()`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedEatCategories: [],
    eatCategories: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Category 1',
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Category 2',
    }, {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Category 3',
    }, {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Category 4',
    }, {
      id: 5,
      title: 'Category 5',
    }],
    posts: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Product 1',
        eat_categories: [{
          id: 1,
        }]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Product 2',
        eat_categories: [{
            id: 1,
          },
          {
            id: 2,
          },
          {
            id: 3,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Product 3',
        eat_categories: [{
            id: 1,
          },
          {
            id: 5,
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPlaces: function() {
      return this.posts.filter(post => 
        post.eat_categories.some(tag => 
          this.checkedEatCategories.includes(tag.id)
        )
      )
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="eatCategory in eatCategories">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" :value="eatCategory.id" v-model="checkedEatCategories">
        <span class="title">{{eatCategory.title}}</span>
     </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="post in filteredPlaces">
      {{ post.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you best solution.